# GNU Emacs on Big Sur acting as if Control, Option keys sticky

Tags: keyboard, emacs

I'm a longtime GNU Emacs and macOS (and GNU Emacs *on* macOS) user, on a US Gov't owned MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) running macOS 11.6.3 (Big Sur).

For the last few weeks, GUI versions of Emacs are acting as if the Control or Meta key was being held down for a few seconds after it was released. Needless to say, this makes editing particularly painful.

This has happened with both the MacPorts and emacsformacosx dot com builds of Emacs 28.1, *and* with older Emacsen running in Linux virtual machines!

Emacs running in the macOS Terminal app is not affected.

The problem does not affect other Mac apps, *unless* I am switching context from Emacs to some other app.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? How can I chase down the cause of this problem?

Comment: Turn off Sticky Keys in Accessibility?

Comment: I've checked several times. Sticky Keys and Slow Keys are off.